# Hide title tag on Tabulator's cells

Tags: javascript, tabulator

every time I hover over a cell, the title appears. This is default behavior of Tabulator and I can't find this on the docs (http://tabulator.info)

```html
<div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="name" title="<img src="/open-delimiter.png" data-id="1" width="27px" height="19px" alt="">Billy Bob" style="width: 701px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center; height: 58px;">
    <p class="p-name-inside-table" contenteditable="true"><img src="/open-delimiter.png" data-id="1" width="27px" height="19px" alt="">
        Billy Bob
    </p>
</div>
```

[image]

How do I hide it?

Comment: what plugin you are referring to?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the tabulator library. This is the expected behavior of the title attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

Comment: what I mean by "default behavior of Tabulator" is that the library adds the title tag under the hood and I think this is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this : `tooltips:false`,  //hide tool tips on cells

Comment: jeez. I also just can remove it from the options 